# restore nuget in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nuget

When I tried to use Jenkins as our CI environment to build ASP.NET project, I set up to use MSBuild.exe to build project. But when the cmd run into restore nuget packages, it stuck. The error message is as below:

> Unable to find version '2.5.48' of package 'SlowCheetah'.
>         https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json:
>
> Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>          An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server.
>
> A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
>   [2606:2800:133:206e:1315:22a5:2006:24fd]:443

But if I use windows command line to run the msbuild, it is working and could download the pkg from nuget.org. **Error only happened when try to build in Jenkins**

NB : jenkins is running like a windows service and he is used by an administrator account